# SearchView for a RecyclerView within a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app that lists books by category in a Recyclerview.
The category list is dynamic; each user will see different categories based on their profile.
The list of books are also in a (horizontal) Recyclerview, also dynamic and depends on what books the user has access to.

Something like this:

```
Category 1
<List of books>
Category 2
<List of books>
```

How do I go about adding a SearchView with a custom adapter for ALL the books retrieved?

This is my main activity.

**BrowseBooksActivity** It has two functions:

1. fetchBooks - gets a list of categories
2. fetchBooksByCategory - loops through the list of categories to get list of books

   ```
   class BrowseBooksActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.browsebooksmain_layout)

       fetchBooks(this)
       recyclerview_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

   }

   fun fetchBooks (context: Context) {
       val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
       val token = sp.getString(PREF_TOKEN, "")
       val url = URL + "/tags?type=level"
       val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
           @Throws(IOException::class)
           override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
               val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                       .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                       .build()
               println(newRequest)
               return chain.proceed(newRequest)
           }
       }).build()

       val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()


           client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
               override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                   val jsonData = response?.body()?.string()
                   val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                   val tagList: List<Tags> = gson.fromJson(jsonData, object : TypeToken<List<Tags>>() {}.type)

                  fetchBooksByCategory(context, tagList)

     }
    }
   }


   fun fetchBooksByCategory (context: Context, tagList: List<Tags>) {
       val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
       val token = sp.getString(PREF_TOKEN, "")
       val count = tagList.size
       var bookListByGroup: HashMap<String, List<ResourcesList>> = HashMap()

       for ((idx, tag: Tags) in tagList.withIndex()) {

           var tagName = tag.name
           tagName.replace(" ","%20")
           var url = URL + "/me/resources?resourceType.name=version2&tags.name=" + tagName
           var client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
               @Throws(IOException::class)
               override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                   val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                           .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                           .build()
                   return chain.proceed(newRequest)
               }
           }).build()

           var request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()


               client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                   override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                       val jsonData = response?.body()?.string()
                       val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                       val bookList: List<ResourcesList> = gson.fromJson(jsonData, object : TypeToken<List<ResourcesList>>() {}.type)

                       if (bookList.isNotEmpty()) {
                           bookListByGroup!!.put(tag.name,bookList)
                       }


                       if (idx == (count - 1)) {
                         //last index
                           runOnUiThread {
                               recyclerview_main.adapter = BrowseBooksAdapter(context,bookListByGroup)
                           }
                       }        
       }
   }
   }
   ```

**BrowseBooksAdapter**:

```
class BrowseBooksAdapter (val context: Context, val bookListByGroup : HashMap<String, List<ResourcesList>>?): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>()  {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return bookListByGroup!!.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.browsebooks_layout, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val keyList = ArrayList(bookListByGroup!!.keys)
        val valueList = ArrayList(bookListByGroup!!.values)

        holder?.v?.book_category.text = keyList[position]
        var booksByCategory : List<ResourcesList>? = valueList[position]

        holder?.v.inner_recyclerview.adapter = BooksByCategoryAdapter(booksByCategory)
        holder?.v.inner_recyclerview.layoutManager = CustomLinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

}
```

**BooksByCategoryAdapter**

```
class BooksByCategoryAdapter (val booksByCategory: List<ResourcesList>?): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomVH>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return booksByCategory!!.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomVH {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bookcontainer_layout, parent, false)
        return CustomVH(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomVH, position: Int) {
        holder.booksByCategory = booksByCategory!![position]
        Picasso.get().load(booksByCategory!![position].coverURI).into(holder?.v?.inner_bookcover)
    }
}

class CustomVH(val v: View, var booksByCategory : ResourcesList? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    init {
        v.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent (v.context, ReadBooksActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("ID", booksByCategory!!.id)
            v.context.startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: To me the question "How do I go about adding a SearchView with a custom adapter for ALL the books retrieved?" is not clear ... where is the problem? What do you want to know? Your adapter has the data set(s), so if you want to find a book, you'll simply search the data set for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, however If you want to show all data and after that if you want to search by category with custom adapter you can use this method

1. Add search_menu.xml in /res/menu

   `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     tools:context="com.learn2crack.recyclerviewsearch.MainActivity">
    <item
       android:id="@+id/search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
       android:title="Search"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
       app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
     </menu>`
2. attach serach_menu to your activity onCreateOptionsMenu

   `@Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
       MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
       SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
       MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
     //Calling function to search the text you entered in your custom adapter
       search(searchView); 
     }`
3. Search function

   : This function will be called after entering text in search menu.

> Here Old_Adapter is the adapter which you sent to recyclerview to display content. You have to create new adapter object with the data matched with your searched string and call recyclerview with this new adapter

```
    private void search(SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setQueryHint("SOME_CATEGORY"); //Mention what you want to search as hint
    searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }


        //Your searched text will appear as newText
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            //Create new object of your custom adapter
            List<AnyAdapter> searchcategory = new ArrayList<>();

            //Old_Adapter is your adapter with which you sent data to your Recyclerview
            for (int x = 0; x < Old_Adapter.size(); x++) {

                //Fetch data from your Old_Adapter
                final AnyAdapter newSearch = Old_Adapter.get(x);
                String cat = newSearch.getCategory();

                //compare the data with searched text add newSearch adapter to new Adapter created earlier  
                if (cat.contains(newText)) {
                    searchcategory.add(newSearch);
                }
            }
            if (newText.isEmpty()) { //If searched text is empty then pass Old_Adapter to your recyclerview again
                callRecyclerview(Old_Adapter);
            } else{ //Else call recyclerview with new Adapter
                callRecyclerview(searchcategory);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```